# How to call a method of another activity in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've an activity where I receive data via BLE and display it (ControlActivity).
There's a second activity where I want to display the received data in a different way (OnlineActivity).

In ControlActivity there's a method that get's called when data is received via BLE:

```
private fun onNotificationReceived(bytes: ByteArray){
    if(bytes[0] == 0x01){
        //handle with ControlActivity
    }
    else if(bytes[0] == 0x02){
        //handle with OnlineActivity
        //startedinstanceofOnlineActivity?.handleData(bytes)
    }
}
```

Data comes in about every second periodically.

There's a button in the ControlActivity which should start the OnlineActivity:

```
control_online.setOnClickListener {
    val intent = Intent(this,OnlineActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

To call a method of OnlineActivity from ControlActivity I would need the Instance of OnlineActivity that is created/started here.
The method in OnlineActivity should change a few textViews in OnlineActivity based on the data from ControlActivity.

onNotificationReceived gets also called continuously, when OnlineActivity is active.

I just need a "quick and dirty"-solution for my problem, as this is just a very basic test-app for myself. I don't want to invest too much time with TabViews, etc..
I'm just an embedded software-engineer who wants to display his received data in any way for testing purposes. I never developed an app before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a quick solution, You can declare a static variables for data that You received in `onNotificationReceived` of `ControlActivity`

To crate a static variables, You will define those variables inside companion object

And you can get that data via class name like `ControlActivity.foo` inside your OnlineActivity (where `foo` is the static variable inside ControlActivity)

Comment: Thank you, that really helped me!
I totally forgot about the static keyword, since it's a bit different in non OOP.

Comment: this can cause leaks. you can use singleton class if need be

Comment: @Raghunandan I've actually done it like that. I've added a class called `MessageHandler`. `ControlActivity` has a single instance inside companion object. `OnlineActivity` gets that instance via `ControlActivity.msghdl`.